# Cannot store lists - Realm Swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am trying to create a one to many relationship between medication table and side effects table. `RealmObject` is a custom class created from `Object` class.

Model definitions:

```
class Medication: RealmObject {

    @objc dynamic var name : String?
    @objc dynamic var form : String?
    @objc dynamic var id : String?

    let medToSideEffect = List<SideEffect>()

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}


class SideEffect: RealmObject {

    @objc dynamic var masterSideEffectId : String = ""
    @objc dynamic var entityType : String = ""
    @objc dynamic var entityId : String = ""
    @objc dynamic var sideEffect : String = ""
    @objc dynamic var id : String = ""
    @objc dynamic var uniqueId : String = ""

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "uniqueId"
    }
}
```

Test code:

```
let medicationItem = Medication(dict: medication)

let sideEffectItems = List<SideEffect>()
for sideEffect in sideEffectList {
    let sideEffectItem = SideEffect()
    sideEffectItem.id = self.getMongoId()
    sideEffectItem.entityType = "Medicine"
    sideEffectItem.entityId = medicationItem.id!
    sideEffectItem.sideEffect = (sideEffect as? String)!
    sideEffectItem.uniqueId = "\(medicationItem.id!)_\(((sideEffect as? NSString)?.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "_"))!)"

    sideEffectItems.append(sideEffectItem)
    medicationItem.medToSideEffect.append(sideEffectItem)
}
```

After this process, when i print the `medicationItem`,  Output is this

```
Medication {
    name = Paracetomol 650mg;
    form = tab;
    id = 5af96e79efb27f6bd5c25a66;
}
```

The side effects were supposed to be added to the medication object. but that is not the case anymore. It was working fine until the latest update Realm 3.11.0.

Please let me know, if the code is incorrect.

Comment: I would just make 'let sideEffects = List<SideEffect>()' as one attribute of Medication

Comment: How do we know that `sideEffectList` isn’t empty in your test?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson  it is not empty. I logged the array just in case.

Comment: @ValW  I don't think that is gonna make a difference here.

Comment: My point with asking was that all information isn’t available to us so it’s hard to understand why it isn’t working. I think the best way forward is to use the debugger to see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because yYou declare your list as 'immutable', and maybe because your list is a struct and therefore a copy is returned.

```
let medToSideEffect = List<SideEffect>()
```

And so it cannot be changed.  Try (warning untested code)

```
public private(set) var medToSideEffect = List<SideEffect>()
```

and add a func

```
public func append(sideEffect: SideEffect) {
    self.medToSideEffect.append(sideEffect)
}
```

The 'public private (set)' bit means that the list is visible externally but can only be modified by the owning class instance.

Comment: That's not the case. You are supposed to declare `List` properties as being immutable, since `List` is a reference type and in most cases you don't want to change the reference to the `List`, you only want to mutate the elements of it, which is still possible if its declares as immutable.

Comment: Whoops, my bad.  I was thinking 'Swift' not 'Realm Swift'.  Now where is that 'embarassed' emoji?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52704564/6700116
Found the solution.

Go to your target `Build Settings` and set `Reflection Metadata Level` flag to `All`

The issue is discussed here.
https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/5944#issuecomment-426948127